# Something wrong with my HTML/CSS/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Without any script tags, the HTML and CSS work fine. After I add the script and I load the page nothing appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>E-Chef: Homepage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/stephenhjb/Desktop/Html:Css:JQuery/E-Chef/Stylesheets/E-Chef.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=border>
        <h1 class="header big">E-Chef: All your recipes in one place. Online.</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('div').animate({'fontSize+=36'}, 2000, 'linear');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the E-Chef.css file:

```
.header {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    color: #5F9EA0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF7F50;
    border: 30px dotted #FAEBD7;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.big {
    font-size: 36px;
}
.border {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Try put this `script` on bottom of the code.

Comment: `<div class=border>`? `<div class='border'>`

Comment: @PHPglue Um… that was a copy/paste error…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to close the first `script` tag.

Do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: more exactly, `script` tags are not self-closing, meaning they cannot be used like `<script..... />` alone. More on this can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984/2037924

**EDIT #2**: to answer the 2nd part of your question: you'll have to exclude the option of `fontSize` from the quotes (`'`) in the `animate` function. Also you're using the incorrect selector, it's actually the font size of the `h1` element that you want to increase, not the `div`'s, so change it like this:

```
$('h1').animate({ fontSize: '+=36'}, 2000, 'linear');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y0xkz4un/1/

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, but my JQuery still doesn’t work. What should I do? Tell me if you want to see my JQuery-1.5.2.js

Comment: if this answers your question, accept it as the correct one (big gray check mark), if you have another question, post it as new, someone will answer it, i'm sure (i need to go to bed now :)

Comment: Are you hosting jQuery locally or are you pulling it from a CDN?

Comment: well, i'll appreciate if you'll do it after 8 minutes, if you'll still be here ;)

Comment: @James think you meant to ask this on the original question, not in this answer, right?

Comment: just answered your 2nd question ;)